# Converting relative s path into relative c path in svg

Tags: svg, path, coordinate-transformation

i was wondering how is the first relative control point of the "s" command calculated in respect to the previous command "c". 
Lets say, how would i do this if i have c(-7.3 43 22.5 109 26.6 118.4)s(7.3 15.8 8.3 17.7)?

What would the equivavlent c (xy xy xy) c (xy xy xy) be? And how is it calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question can be found where the 's' and 'c' path commands are defined - the SVG specification.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands

Comment: Thanks, i managed to get it how it works by trial and error. And thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

To share the actual translation from C + S to C + C:

> (S usually comes after C [or another S], if not then it's x1,y1-coordinates use the current location)

Original: **C x1,y1 x2,y2 x,y S x2,y2 x,y**

Target: **C x1,y1 x2,y2 x,y C x1,y1 x2,y2 x,y**

```
C.x1 = 2 * C.x - C.x2
C.y1 = 2 * C.y - C.y2
C.x2 = S.x2
C.y2 = S.y2
C.x = S.x
C.y = S.y
```

Note: This answer uses absolute paths. But the transformation to relative is trivial. (Save the current pen location and add it to the relative paths)